# Why does My Rotation only go Anti Clockwise when I want to go Clockwise?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-animation

```
[CATransaction begin];
            [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5];
            CGAffineTransform currentTransform = squareLayer.affineTransform;
            CGFloat angle = M_PI;

            squareLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, angle);
            [CATransaction commit];
```

and

```
[CATransaction begin];
            [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5];
            CGAffineTransform currentTransform = squareLayer.affineTransform;
            CGFloat angle = (M_PI * -1);

            squareLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, angle);
            [CATransaction commit];
```

I would have thought the -1 would have reversed the direction but apparently not?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The angle is the same. To go full circle you need 2 * Pi, so half a circle is Pi. If you take -Pi it would end at the same point.

EDIT: If you need to make it turn clockwise you can go slightly off -Pi. Instead of -M_PI use -3.141593 for example.

Comment: I agree But I need the to rotate 180 clockwise. Whats the best way to active this? Cheers

Comment: Well, it will rotate in the shortest direction. If precision isn't a huge issue you can rotate to slightly below or above 180 degrees. It's a quick and dirty fix but will probably work.

Comment: Just seen your edit. It does work well but does seem like a bit imperfect.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit hacky. But, depending on your needs, it might suffice.

Answer (score 9):

Just ran into this and while @radicalraid's solution works fine, I prefer adjusting the starting angle before rotation vs rotating to an angle less than the desired end point. Also, you can animate `CALayer` transforms using animation blocks.

My code:

```
// iOS will rotate the shortest distance to the end angle,
// using counter-clockwise if equal.
// Force the rotation to open clockwise and close counter-clockwise by bumping
// the initial angle
CGFloat startRadians, endRadians;
if (isOpening) {
    startRadians = 0.01f;
    endRadians = M_PI;

}
else {
    startRadians = M_PI - 0.01f;
    endRadians = 0.0f;
}

self.myImageView.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(startRadians);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                 animations:^{
                     self.myImageView.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(endRadians);
                 }];
```

Answer (score 5):

My experience with Core animatinon does not agree with that Apple quote. What I've found is that the only thing that matters is the final angle value. Positive pi and negative pi rotations result in the same transformation matrix, so the system just goes counter-clockwize regardless.

What I've done to go rotations in a specific direction, or rotations of a full 360 degrees, is to create an explicit CABasicAnimation using a type like transform.rotation.z, with the fill mode set to kCAFillModeForwards, and only provide a toValue. That causes the animation to start from the previous value. You can then set up a rotation that is an even fraction of your total desired rotation, and give it a repeat count.

For example, the code below creates an animation that rotates 5 quarter turns, or 450 degrees. If you wanted to do 180 degrees clockwise, you could a rotation of pi/2 with a repeat count of 2. For counterclockwise, use -pi/2 with a repeat count of 2.

```
  CABasicAnimation* rotate =  [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: 
    @"transform.rotation.z"];
  rotate.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
  rotate.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

  //Do a series of 5 quarter turns for a total of a 1.25 turns
  //(2PI is a full turn, so pi/2 is a quarter turn)
  [rotate setToValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: -M_PI / 2]];
  rotate.repeatCount = 5;

  rotate.duration = duration/rotate.repeatCount * 2 ;
  rotate.beginTime = start;
  rotate.cumulative = TRUE;
  rotate.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction 
    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Instead of -M_PI use -3 * M_PI, for anti-clockwise

and remove '-' sign for opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this previous question: [Force clockwise/anticlockwise rotation for a CABasicAnimation of a UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470082/force-clockwise-anticlockwise-rotation-for-a-cabasicanimation-of-a-uiimageview) the code is a bit different but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quote from the apple documentation "In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a negative value specifies clockwise rotation." Have you tried doing this:

```
squareLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, -M_PI);
```

Thats what I have used to do all my clockwise rotation in the past.

Comment: Yes this is the problem. As you can see in my code above this isn't working. Don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I've used to make it always rotate clockwise `if endAngle > startAngle` and counterClockwise `if startAngle > endAngle`. (e.g. the animation should never "cross the 2*pi line")

```swift
private func rotate(view: UIView, from startAngle: CGFloat, to endAngle: CGFloat) {
    let midAngle = (startAngle.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2 * .pi) + endAngle.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2 * .pi)) / 2

     UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: UIView.inheritedAnimationDuration, delay: 0, options: .calculationModeCubicPaced, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0) {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: midAngle)
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0) {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: endAngle)
        }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

You can call this from inside another UIView.animate block to animate it with other things as well. For example:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
   rotate(view: view, from: .pi * 0.25, to: 1.5 * .pi)
   otherView.alpha = 1
}
```

It's important to use the `.calculationModeCubicPaced` option otherwise you have to manually specify the relative start time and duration

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Duncan and XJones. Final value is all that seems to matter. CA will then find the shortest path.

Using XJones's idea. This seemed to work for me:

```
private let angleRadians = CGFloat(M_PI)
private let angleRadiansOffset = CGFloat(0.1 * M_PI/180.0)

let turnAngle = angleRadians - angleRadiansOffset;

//pre-rotate by an 'invisible amount', to force rotation in the same direction every time
primView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(primView.layer.transform, angleRadiansOffset, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState], animations: { () -> Void in

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 0.8, animations: { () -> Void in

        //now we will complete the rotation to the correct end value
        primView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(primView.layer.transform, turnAngle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

    })

    //... other code ....

}) { (finished) -> Void in

}
```